# 6-bit Full Adder returns with an error

Tags: verilog

```
module adder6(
    output[5:0] sum,
    output c_out,
    input[5:0] a, b,
    input c_in);
wire [1:0] c_o;
adder4 a(.sum([3:0]),c_o[0],.a(a[3:0]), .b(b[3:0),c_in); //4-bits adder
full_adder fa1(sum[4],c_o[1],a[4],b[4],c_o[0]); //1-bit adder
full_adder fa2(sum[5],c_out,a[5],b[5],c_o[1]); //1-bit adder
endmodule

module adder4(
    output[3:0] sum,
    output c_out,       // carry out
    input[3:0] a, b,    // operands
    input c_in);        // carry in

wire [2:0] c_o;
full_adder fa1(sum[0],c_o[0],a[0],b[0],c_in);
full_adder fa2(sum[1],c_o[1],a[1],b[1],c_o[0]);
full_adder fa3(sum[2],c_o[2],a[2],b[2],c_o[1]);
full_adder fa4(sum[3],c_out,a[3],b[3],c_o[2]);
endmodule

module full_adder(
    output sum,
    output c_out,   // carry out
    input a,
    input b,
    input c_in);    // carry in

wire sum1;
wire c_in1;
wire c_out2;
    half_adder ha1(sum1,c_in1,a,b);
    half_adder ha2(sum,c_out2,sum1,c_in);
    or(c_out,c_out2,c_in1);
endmodule


module half_adder(
    output sum,
    output c_out,   // carry out
    input a,
    input b);

assign sum=a^b;
assign c_out=a&&b;

endmodule
```

I have to make a 6-bit adder from an 4-bit adder and two full-adders. I am sure that the problem is within the ***adder6***  module since I have already tested the 4-bit adder module separately, and it works. But I cannot find the mistake. I am not sure if I made the correct connections in the ***adder4*** function that I have used in ***adder6*** module.
(Update 1):

```
module adder6_test;
// Inputs
reg [5:0] a;
reg [5:0] b;

// Outputs
wire [6:0] sum;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
adder6 uut (
    .sum(sum), 
    .a(a), 
    .b(b)
);

initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    a = 0;
    b = 0;

    // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
    #100;

    // Add stimulus here
    a = 50;
    b = 14;
    #10;
    a = 2;
    b = 33;
    #10;
    a = 63;
    b = 63;
end

endmodule
```

(Update 2):
The error is:
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:/Users/Iulia/Downloads/lab1_skel/ex4_skel/adder6.v" Line 10: Syntax error near ")".

```
// Verilog Test Fixture Template

`timescale 1 ns / 1 ps

 module TEST_gate;
      reg <signal1>;
      reg [2:0] <signal2>;
      wire [3:0] <signal3>;
      wire <signal4>;

      <module_name> <instance_name> (
              <port1>,
              <port2>
      );

      integer <name1>;
      integer <name2>;

// The following code initializes the Global Set Reset (GSR) and Global Three-State (GTS) nets
// Refer to the Synthesis and Simulation Design Guide for more information on this process
reg GSR;
assign glbl.GSR = GSR;
reg GTS;
assign glbl.GTS = GTS;

initial begin
  GSR = 1;
  GTS = 0; // GTS is not activated by default
  #100; // GSR is set for 100 ns
  GSR = 0;
end

// Initialize Inputs
  `define auto_init

  `ifdef auto_init

      initial begin
      end

  `endif
endmodule
```

Now I get these errors: 
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:/Users/Iulia/Downloads/lab1_skel/ex4_skel/adder6_test.v" Line 6: Syntax error near "<".

ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:/Users/Iulia/Downloads/lab1_skel/ex4_skel/adder6_test.v" Line 7: Syntax error near "<".

ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:/Users/Iulia/Downloads/lab1_skel/ex4_skel/adder6_test.v" Line 8: Syntax error near "<".

(Update 3) I modified the ***adder6*** module and I managed to get rid of the errors. I used a 7-bit sum, and I've eliminated the carry in. But now, it doesn't calculate the sum. For a=63 and b=63 the sum is X. This is the new adder6 module:

```
module adder6(
output[6:0] sum,
input[5:0] a, 
input[5:0] b);

wire c_out0;
wire c_out1;
adder4 add4(sum[3:0],c_out0,a[3:0],b[3:0],c_in);
full_adder fa3(sum[4],c_out1,a[4],b[4],c_out0);
full_adder fa4(sum[5],sum[6],a[5],b[5],c_out1);
endmodule
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you write what exactly is your problem (i.e. what do you mean by "return errors"?).

Comment: @toolic, yes, this is my code, all the errors I get, I am pretty sure that are because of the syntax i used for the adder4... I don't get why i still get them. In case you forgot :D you helped me yesterday to make the 4-bit adder, i obtained some wrong results until you noticed that i had two outputs switched.

Comment: @IuliaDobra: you **can't** use `<` as 1st character of your signal name.

Comment: The first code is the one that i run, the other ones are the test benches.

Comment: so? You have errors in your testbench.

Comment: I modified the code and I've updated the post. Now I get no errors but somehow it won't calculate the sum

Comment: You do not assign any value to adder4 `c_in` input, so it has value `X`. You need to assign e.g. `0` to it to get a proper result.

Comment: Oh, silly me! You were right. Thanks, now I get the proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `adder6` declaration have this line:

```
adder4 a(.sum([3:0]),c_o[0],.a(a[3:0]), .b(b[3:0),c_in); //4-bits adder
```

As you can see, you've called an instance of `adder4` `a`. At the same time, you've called an input port `a`. That's why you're getting an error when trying to compile your code. The easiest solution would be to rename an `adder4` instance.

Btw that particular line should look a little bit different in case to work:

```
adder4 add(.sum(sum[3:0]), .c_out(c_o[0]), .a(a[3:0]), .b(b[3:0]), .c_in(c_in));
```